# Can I keep my stuff in New Game+?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

Assassin Creed Odyssey has a *very* huge map and so many places to go, so many choices and different endings.

I was wondering if in NG+ I can keep my inventory and stay at my high level. I mean, if I want to play it again, I won't have enough free time to play my other games.

Is it possible to keep everything, or should I save my games at specific times to get back?

My Alexios is mean and angry; I wonder if I can save more lives if my new choices make him soft and friendly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described [here](https://www.pushsquare.com/news/2019/02/guide_assassins_creed_odyssey_new_game_plus_-_how_to_start_what_carries_over) you keep your current level and all your stuff but start the story again with the map reset.

What carries over:

- Your level and mastery levels
- Your unlocked abilities
- All of your weapons and armour
- Your ship upgrades
- Your ship cosmetics
- Any ship lieutenants that you acquired from the in-game store/Ubisoft Club
- All of your resources, including orichalcum
- All of your drachmae

What doesn't carry over:

- Story progression
- Quest progression
- Map markers
- Location completion
- Cultist progression